# jQuery colorbox code review and best practice

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have this colorbox code but I'm not sure if this is the best way. I have another application that is not working because of this. So I think, probably something is wrong with the code below. Do you see a problem? Thanks.

```
var $bootSelectPopup = $('#wraper-boot-select-structures-popup');
            $('#bootstrap-grid-popup').on("click", function(e){
            $bootSelectPopup.show();
            e.preventDefault();                
            $(function(){
            $.colorbox({
                href: $bootSelectPopup,
                transition: 'fade',
                speed: 150,
                fadeOut : 0,
                inline: true,                    
                close : 'x',
                onClosed: function() {
                    $bootSelectPopup.hide();                    
                }

            });

        });
        });
```

Comment: so check your console for error. If any, post it

Comment: Thanks Roasted..I didn't get any error. It just seems that it has a conflict with window.parent(used in another application). But I did not see any console error.